# How can I recreate my database with hibernate pojo files

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jsp

I lost my projects' database from my pc. But I have my JSP project which includes hibernate. Whenever I run the project it says '**org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection**' because the database not exist in the server. Can I recreate my database with the help of the POJO files? I am using netbeans and MySQL server 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can recreate your database using hibernate.
In our session factory you need to set the following property.

```
 <property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
   </props>
 </property>
```

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` Automatically validate or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created

There are a couple of caveats you need to understand:

1. This will only recreate objects which you had mapped.  This process will not recreate any database object which you may have had but didn't have mapped.
2. Certain object names may not be named what they were previously.  One classic example would be the names of your foreign-key constraints.

This will at least get you back up with a majority of what you lost at the very least.

Comment: Thank you @Naros. Sorry I am new to hibernate. After I add this to the session factory. What should I do. Should I redeploy the application?

Comment: Yes. You need to redeploy your application and  check your database after application startup

Comment: You will need to make sure at least the empty database exists and then yes you can redeploy.  After you've deployed, you'll want to remove the property and then redeploy again since you only need to recreate the instance once.

Comment: I have created an empty database with the same name as before. But when I deploy nothing happens. Database is still empty. But when I run the application it says **'java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'**. Please help. @Naros

Comment: @shubham could you please help me?

Comment: You need to also set  this property <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>  and you need to make sure you are pointing to correct db with credentials.  Also set <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> so that you can log queries on application startup

Comment: @DulithaMahishkaRajapaksha Do you have the MySQL jdbc driver on the classpath?  The `ExceptionInInitializerError` is common for people who forget to include it as part of their build pom.xml

Comment: @Naros Yes i have already added the jdbc connector to the classpath. Netbeans output says like this:
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 11; Element type "props" must be declared.`
I think your codes *<props>* tag causing this exception. How do I declare that in the file

Comment: What file are you defining the properties in?

Comment: it worked @Naros. Thank you very much. inside my `<session-factory>`, your code does not work. But I changed it to `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`. And it worked like a charm. Cheers !